# Transfer data from table

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have a table in HTML.

```
<tr class="top">
  <td class="name1"><a href="#">JOHN DOE</a></td>
  <td class="company1">DOE TRUCKING</td>
  <td class="position1">TRUCKER</td>
  <td class="mc1">1234-567-8901</td>
  <td class="dot1">1234-567-8901</td>
  <td class="status1"><img src="images/cross.png" width="12" height="12" alt="cross"></td>
</tr>
```

When I select the name in the table it opens up a popup.

```
<div class="popup1">            

<div class="cross3"><a href="#"><img src="images/closr-arrow.png" width="19" height="19" alt="closr-arrow"></a></div>
    <h3>TABLE NAME</h3>
    <a href="#" class="approve">APPROVE ACCOUNT</a>
    <a href="#" class="deny">DENY ACCOUNT</a>
</div>
```

How do I make it so H3 retains the name that was in my table?

Popup is being shown like so:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.name1 a').click(function(e) {
$('.popup1').lightbox_me({

    });
```

Comment: You're going to want to give your elements some IDs and you can easily do this with Vanilla JS, just using `innerHTML`

Comment: How is the popup being shown? (By which I mean, what JS do you have already?)

Comment: Could be done with a pseudo element and data-atrribute in CSS

Comment: See edits please I'm sorry.

Comment: your popup code is incomplete, please fix

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tq8k9/) I don't know how you handle your popup but this is how your js should be structured.

```
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
      $('h3').html($(this).html())
    });
});
```

Comment: For some reason the popup is no longer showing with that code.

Comment: Paste the entire code so we can inspect where is your error

Comment: See my edits. That's how I am doing the popup. For yours I simply added the this part to the lightbox section.

Answer (score -1):

With the assumption that popup opens when you click on the `<a>` then you could just use `$(this).text()` and do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.name1 a').click(function() {
           $('.popup1 h3').text($(this).text());
        });
    });
```

Full example:

```
<table><td class="name1"><a href="#">JOHN DOE</a></td>
          <td class="company1">DOE TRUCKING</td>
          <td class="position1">TRUCKER</td>
          <td class="mc1">1234-567-8901</td>
          <td class="dot1">1234-567-8901</td>
          <td class="status1"><img src="images/cross.png" width="12" height="12" alt="cross"></td>
</table>

<div class="popup1">
    <div class="cross3"><a href="#"><img src="images/closr-arrow.png" width="19"   height="19" alt="closr-arrow"></a></div>
    <h3>TABLE NAME</h3>
    <a href="#" class="approve">APPROVE ACCOUNT</a>
    <a href="#" class="deny">DENY ACCOUNT</a>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.name1 a').click(function() {
            $('.popup1').lightbox_me({}); // <-- whatever your popup is, it plays no role here
            $('.popup1 h3').text($(this).text());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Sorry, you say lightbox but I cannot see how it's called or what lightbox given that lightbox is more of a gallery thing.

That's why I have used jQueryUI dialog instead, if this will not help then someone should take away your keyboard, and I hope this one will save you some duplication too (guessing given your class names).

```
<?php

$rows=array(
    0=>array("id"=>'1',"name"=>'Tom',"company"=>'U',"status"=>'active'),
    1=>array("id"=>'2',"name"=>'Hre',"company"=>'E',"status"=>'suspended'),
    2=>array("id"=>'3',"name"=>'Peter',"company"=>'Pawtucket',"status"=>'wasted'),
    3=>array("id"=>'4',"name"=>'Griffin',"company"=>'Patriot',"status"=>'drunk'),
);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <link href="/jquery-ui-1.10.4/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-ui-1.10.4/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>
        <style>
            .name {color:#00F;}
        </style>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){    
            $("#popup").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                width: 500,
                height: 500,
                title: "Content From Row",
                closeOnEscape: true,
                closeText: "fechar",
                show: {
                    effect: "fadeIn",
                    duration: 1000
                },
                hide: {
                    effect: "fadeOut",
                    duration: 1000
                }
            });
        });
        </script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.name a').click(function() {
                    $('#popup h3').text($(this).text());
                    $(this).parent().siblings().each(function(){
                        if($(this).hasClass('company')){
                            $('#popup .popup_company').text($(this).text());
                        }
                        if($(this).hasClass('status')){
                            $('#popup .popup_status').text($(this).text());
                        }
                    });
                    $("#popup").dialog('open');
                });
            });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <?php 
        if(is_array($rows)){
            ?><table>
                <tr><td>Row No</td><td>ID</td><td>Name</td><td>Company</td><td>Status</td></tr>    
            <?php
            foreach($rows as $row_key=>$row){
                ?><tr><?php
                    if(is_array($row)){
                        echo('<td>'.$row_key.'</td>');
                        foreach($row as $value_key=>$value){
                            if($value_key == "name"){
                                echo('<td class='.$value_key.'><a>'.$value.'</a></td>');
                            }else{
                                echo('<td class='.$value_key.'>'.$value.'</td>');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ?></tr><?php
            }
            ?></table><?php
        }
        ?>

        <div style="display:none;"><div id="popup">
            <div class="cross3">
                <a href="#"><img src="images/closr-arrow.png" width="19"   height="19" alt="closr-arrow"></a>
            </div>
            <h3>TABLE NAME</h3>
            <a href="#" class="popup_company"></a>
            <a href="#" class="popup_status"></a>
            <a href="#" class="approve">APPROVE ACCOUNT</a>
            <a href="#" class="deny">DENY ACCOUNT</a>
        </div></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't matter I was right that u were using click on a as trigger

Comment: I need the lightbox code for this to work. Lightbox is the one doing my popup......

Comment: @user3792038 then fix your posted script, and you dont need it to change the h3 or proove the concept

Comment: The popup obviously plays some sort of a role if it's what I want the item to be displayed in. Cannot test otherwise....

Comment: @user3792038 Just put `$('.popup1 h3').text($(this).text());` below within same `.click(func....` code as that lightbox thing