# Lightbox not showing Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to show a popover upon a link being selected in my HTML table.

Here is my table:

```
<table width="1150" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr class="inner1-top">
    <td class="name">NAME</td>
    <td class="company">COMPANY</td>
    <td class="position">POSITION</td>
    <td class="mc">MC #</td>
    <td class="dot">DOT #</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="inner2-top">
  </tr>
</table>
```

I fill that table using the following Javascript:

```
$('.inner2-top').append('<tr><td class="name"><a href="#">'+ 
  object.get('username') + '</a></td><td class="company">' + 
  object.get('company') + '</td><td class="position">' + 
  object.get('position') + '</td><td class="mc">' + 
  object.get('mc') + '</td><td class="dot">' +
  object.get('dot') + '</td><td>');
})(jQuery);
```

I am trying to make it so when the name is clicked my popover will show:

```
$(document).ready(function(){           
  $('.name1 a').click(function(e) {
    $('.popup1').lightbox_me({

    });
```

Unfortunately this does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: What is lightbox_me? Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: If you want to bind jQuery events to elements added to the DOM dynamically, try `$(document).on('click', '.name a', function(){CODE GOES HERE});`

Comment: Irvin. Lightbox is a simple popover class.

Comment: @user3792038: beercodebeer is right, you have to bind elements to your function in a different way if you want to support also dynamically added elements. Pay attention that the code to apply depends on the jquery reference. In the past, it was the 'live' but now it's 'on'. Refer to this site http://www.sitepoint.com/on-vs-live-review/

Comment: @beercodebeer how would I do that formatted with my existing structure?

Comment: @user3792038 wow , just wow, downvote me but accept this one, just wow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24701412/transfer-data-from-table/24701507#24701507

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use `document.on` to bind jQuery events to dynamically added elements, working with your existing structure, try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.name a', (function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();//to prevent the browser from following the link or reloading the page
        $('.popup1').lightbox_me({
            //whatever other code is necessary for your lightbox
        });
)};
```

[jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)