# innerHTML doesn't loop table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Right now I have a table in my web application:

```
<tr class="inner2-top">
</tr>
```

The table's data is filled by looping through elements from my web database and adding that data accordingly.

```
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
      var object = results[i];
        (function($) {
        $('.inner2-top').append('<tr><td class="name1"><a href="#">'+ 
              object.get('username') + '</a></td><td class="company1">' + 
              object.get('dot') + '</td><td>');            
      })(jQuery);
    }
```

I then display the username from the table in a popover.

```
        $(document).on('click', '.name1 a', function(e){
        $('#para').html($('td.name1').html());
            $('.popup1').lightbox_me({
    });
```

What I am noticing is that the popup is only displaying the name for the first item in the table and not the second. For example, say the table is structured like so:

Row 1: Anthony

Row 2: David

When I select row 1, Anthony shows in the popover.

When I select row 2, Anthony also shows in the popover.

Any ideas why this is occuring?

Comment: You're putting a `tr` inside a `tr`, which is invalid, and then you have a `stray `<td>` at the end for some reason.

Comment: look here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24701412/transfer-data-from-table/24701507#24701507 why did you split your thing into 3questions

Answer (score 0):

Try having this in your function when calling the html function

```
$(document).on('click', '.name1 a', function(e){
    $('#para').html($(this).html());
        $('.popup1').lightbox_me({
});
```

[JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GsK96/1/)